# Proving plane geometry problem

Tags: proof-verification, plane-geometry, angle

Given 8 lines on a plane and no two of them are parallel. Prove that, at least two of them form an angle less than 23°.

I have checked this out using different angles and the statement seems to be true. But that isn't the proof I guess. How do I prove this, could anybody help me with this?

Comment: *Hint*; $180^\circ\div 8=22.5^\circ$

Comment: Yeah I've done that bit already but I don't know how to to use it for proving this thing

Comment: Imagine $8$ lines parallel to the given ones, but passing through the origin.